# how to using ember.js to develop multiply platform app

Tags: css, ember.js, media-queries

I want to realize multiply platform using ember.js.For iPhone,smart phones the designs are the same,while the iPad design and resolution are not the same.
*For phones,it will contain headerbar and appBody outlet*

```
    "<div class='wrapper'>" +
    "{{outlet topHeaderBar}}" +
    "{{outlet appBody}}" +

"<nav class='nav'>"+
```

While for the iPad,it will contain the below  iPad application templates

```
 "<div class='wrapper'>"+
    "<nav class='nav'>"+
    "{{outlet leftPanel}}" +
    "{{outlet rightPanel}}" +
```

Therefore, **how can I define my AppRoute to render the different outlet once the CSS recognize the devices.**
In the above case,I thought I can reuse the topHeaderBar and the appBody for the leftPanel and rightPanel.
But the question is **how can I render to different templates in my AppRoute?**
Kindly give suggestions.
Thank u!

Comment: And I wonder to find some source code of ember.js which can help in recognize the device type,so that it's better to define the redender action in AppRoute

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries) as follows. In your handlebars template:

```
<div class="show-ipad">
  {{outlet "ipad-outlet1"}}
  {{outlet "ipad-outlet2"}}
</div> 

<div class="show-iphone">
  {{outlet "iphone-outlet1"}}
  {{outlet "iphone-outlet2"}}
</div>
```

In your stylesheet (media-queries taken from [this article)](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/):

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  .show-iphone {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .show-ipad {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Adapt the media-queries to your needs (targeting iPads in landscape, in portrait, etc.).

In Javascript don't assume anything about the client device. Just render all outlets for all devices, and let the CSS media-query handle what is shown and what is hidden.

Comment: Is there any way which I can get the flag of the device type in js?So can I use this flag in the functions to render different template?

Comment: You can use the `navigator.userAgent` property (there are probably some libraries that wrap the user-agent detection). I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Comment: Thank u,I tried the method you suggested,but on the browser, all temaplates will be shown.As for the navigator.userAgent,it works buy it seems only can put the code inside the head.                        ' <script type="text/javascript">
      var device;
      if (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  device='Firefox';
  
  };'